# Is it possible to union two tables with different field types in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to union two tables together but one of the columns is a nullable int and the other is an int. I tried casting the int column to a nullable int but get the error

> "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

```
TableA
int? SupplierId
string SupplierName

TableB
int SupplierId
string Name
```

```
string result;
using (var db = Dal.MyEntities(false))
{
    result = db.TableA
                .Select(c => new { SupplierId = c.SupplierID, SupplierName = c.SupplierName })
                .Union(db.TableB.Select(g => new { (int?)g.SupplierId, SupplierName = g.Name }))
                .Where(c => c.SupplierId == supplierId)
                .Select(c => c.SupplierName)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) :

> You must provide a name for a property that is being initialized with
>   an expression

In your case, you should provide property for expression in which you are casting to `Nullable int type`

```
    result = db.TableA
                .Select(c => new { SupplierId = c.SupplierID, SupplierName = c.SupplierName })
                .Union(db.TableB.Select(g => new { SupplierId = (int?)g.SupplierId, SupplierName = g.Name }))
                .Where(c => c.SupplierId == supplierId)
                .Select(c => c.SupplierName)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```